# Eliminate a single element type from XML using XQUERY

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

Here is my problem... I need to select everything in an entire xml document, but leaving out one tag. Unfortunately, this tag can vary in depth.

Using the following code sample, I would like to remove all `<crud>`, `<crud2>` and `<...>` (etc.) elements. `<crud>` could have more children, but I don't want them anyways.

```
<body>
  <h2/>
  <crud>
    <crud2/>
    <...>
  </crud>
  <div>
    <p> </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
    </p>
    <crud>
      <crud2/>
      <...>
    </crud>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried a few methods.

```
let $body := "the xml sample"
return $body/*[fn:not(descendant-or-self::crud)]
```

This method takes to much. It removes the entire `<div>` block that contains crud, but I need the `<div>` and the `<p>` that is included.
All other methods seem to only remove the direct `<crud>` children of `<body>` or it removes the container as well.

So, I essentially need a method that reaches in every element and removes all the `<crud>` without taking anything else.

The final XML should look like this:

```
<body>
  <h2/>
  <div>
    <p> </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I greatly appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This kind of processing is most easily done with XSLT, which is more expressive than XQuery**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="crud"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<body>
    <h2/>
    <crud>
        <crud2/>
    </crud>
    <div>
        <p> </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>     </p>
        <crud>
            <crud2/>
        </crud>
    </div>
</body>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<body>
    <h2/>

    <div>
        <p> </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>     </p>

    </div>
</body>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node "as-is'.
2. A single template overrides the identity rule/template. It matches anu `crud` element and its empty body results in `crud` (and any subtree topped by it) to be stripped off the output.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm on the right track now, but I seem to be having one more problem. What if crud is preambled with a namespace throughout the document. So `<crud>` is actually `<some:crud>`. I have changed the match in the xslt to some:crud, but now I get "Prefix some has no namespace binding".

Comment: Oh.. Got it. Declare the namespace in the root tag. `<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:some="http://....">`. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy job using [XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Update) and its [copy-statement](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Update#Non-Updating_Expressions):

```
copy $c := .
modify delete node $c//crud
return $c
```

If you can change your original file, you could even use the shorter `delete node //crud`.